# Interact with a wxPython frame in both directions from another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I have already read 
http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks
http://wiki.wxpython.org/CallAfter
and searched a lot in Google but found no answer to my problem. Because in my opinion it would be to much code and it is more a theoretical problem, I hope it is ok without code.

What I want to do with an example: I have a grid (wx.grid) with check boxes in the main thread. Then I start a new thread (thread.start_new_thread) where I go through all rows (1 second per row) and check if the checkbox is set. If it is set, some job is done.

This is working, if I read out all rows **before** I start the thread. But I need to read it out **while** the thread is running, because the user should have the ability to uncheck or check another checkbox! But if I read it out in the new thread sometimes a "NonType Object is not callable" error is raised. I think because wx.CallAfter should be used to interact with the grid in the other thread. But CallAfter I can not use to get the return value.

I have no idea how to solve this issue. Perhaps some people with more thread experience have some idea? If you need additional data please ask, but I think that my example contains all necessary information.

Comment: I guess that binding checkbox change event to a handler which would do "some job" is not possible, because "some job" is too long to do?

Comment: Yes, that's right. In the job I do some things like a telnet request etc. So the event would make the software to in-reactive. Now it's solved the way that no event happens and when the user checked all checkboxes he starts the process with a button.

Comment: Well, I have solution for your problem but I have no idea how to read the checkbox values in grid. Do you have minimal runnable example which would demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Use `wx.Timer` to periodically check your checkbox values and create a new thread only for "some job" when correct checkbox configuration is checked.

Comment: The problem is, it would be to complex for a minimum example. No, I can not make it this way. The user interaction should be like this:
1. The user checks all rows which should be processed 2. The process starts after a button is clicked by processing each checked row from top to bottom. The row which is currently processed is colored to indicate it 3. While this process goes on, the user should be able to check a new row or to uncheck a checked row.

Comment: So the same thing. Start `wx.Timer` which would go and read one row per second. So the timer goes off every second, takes next row and reads the value. If it is checked, it starts a new thread. Reading the checkbox and coloring the row is fast enough for event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach to this type of thing is to use a Queue.Queue object to pass commands to one or more worker threads.  The worker thread(s) will wait on a pull from the queue until there are items in the queue ready to be pulled.  Part of the command object could be a target in the GUI thread to send a message to (in a thread-safe way, like with wx.CallAfter) when the command is completed.

You should also take a look at the wx.lib.delayedresult module.  It is similar to the above but a little more capable and robust.